# How to construct derived class from base?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, constructor

Is there a way to cast base class to derived, calling default constructor?
I'm receiving network data, writing it to packets, then calling protocol function which I wish to parse data differently.

```
class BasePacket {
protected:
    std::vector<char> data;
public:    
    BasePacket(){data.reserve(2048);}
    BasePacket(char* _data, int len){ data.assign(&data[0], &data[len]); }
};

class ActionPacket : public BasePacket {
public:
    char Action;
    char Job;
    ActionPacket(){
        Action = data[0];
        Job = data[1];
    }
};
```

I would like to do something like:

```
void ProcessPacket(BasePacket& packet){
    if (packet.data[0] == 1){
        auto t = (ActionPacket)packet;
        if(t.Job == 1){
            //dosmth
        }
    }
 
    if (packet.data[0] == 2){
        auto t = (OtherPacket)packet;
        if(t.smth){
            //do another smth
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you're storing different levels of abstraction in the same class. You might consider having one class that represents the "raw" stream (i.e. just a `vector<char>`) and then *parsing* it into the actual data. Storing both in the same class is likely to just create leaky abstractions down the line.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo that's the thing in the example, I have one base class that storing only `vector<char>` and derived classes that parse that vector differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your instance is initially a `BasePacket` object, why not just code like `ActionPacket::ActionPacket(BasePacket&)`? That's because `ActionPacket` have some members that `BasePacket` doesn't have, reallocation seems inevitable. Just like this:

```cpp
class ActionPacket
{
    ActionPacket(BasePacket& basePacket) :BasePacket(basePacket), Action(data[0]), Job(data[1]) {};
};
// assuming there is a legal BasePacket object called basePacket
auto actionPacket = ActionPacket{basePacket};
```

BUT, if you are sure that this `BasePacket` object will ONLY be used for constructing `ActionPacket` here and will never be used afterwards, you can write `ActionPacket::ActionPacket(BasePacket&&)` and use `std::move` like this:

```cpp
class ActionPacket
{
    ActionPacket(BasePacket&& basePacket) :BasePacket(std::move(basePacket)), Action(data[0]), Job(data[1]) {};
};
// assuming there is a legal BasePacket object called basePacket
auto actionPacket = ActionPacket{std::move(basePacket)};
```

This will be more efficient since `std::vector` is moved but not re-constructed.

If your instance is initially an `ActionPacket` object, and there are no virtual methods, `static_cast` is acceptable; But if there are some virtual methods, `dynamic_cast` is what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I got idea. The second option seems fine to me and it worked. I'm a bit nervous about 2 moves. Is this fine or maybe there's a way I can construct a BasePacket change pointer to vector etc

Comment: @TylerDense Definitely fine, that's the standard code. In [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) there is some similar code.